# mysqli_fetch_array() or mysqli_fetch_all()?

Tags: php, mysqli

I see comparisons between `mysqli_fetch_array()` and `mysqli_fetch_all()` that say that with `mysqli_fetch_all()` it will take more memory and I will have to iterate over the array.

`mysqli_fetch_all()` is one call to `mysqli` but `mysqli_fetch_array()` is one call per row, for example 100 calls.

I don't know how the mysqli processing works: is calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` really more efficient when you also take the number of calls into account?

(I already understand that the returned data can be associative arrays or not)

Comment: Don't confuse database calls to execute a query and calls to retrieve a record from a resultset..... they're totally different beasts

Comment: Progress. Thanks!, So the whole resultset is returned from the database and used locally by mysqli. Not that the resultset is dripped back?

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with whatever *efficiency*. It's all about *usability* only.

`fetch_all()` is a thing that is called a "syntax sugar" - a shorthand to automate a frequently performed operation. It can be easily implemented as a userland function:

```
function mysqli_fetch_all ($resouce, $mode = MYSQLI_BOTH)
{
    $ret = [];
    while ($row = $resource->fetch_array($mode))
    {
        $ret[] = $row;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Thus you can tell use cases for these functions:

- `fetch_all()` have to be used if you need *an array*, consists of all the returned rows, that will be used elsewhere.
- `fetch_assoc()` in a loop have to be used if you're going to process all the rows one by one right in place.

As simple as that.

These functions bear different purpose and thus there is no point in comparing them.

Note that PDO is tenfold more sweet in terms of syntax sugar, as it's `fetchAll()` function can return data in [dozens different formats](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall)

Answer (score 2):

[From PHP's page on `mysql_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#116673):

> I tested using `fetch_all` versus `while` / `fetch_array` and:
>
> **`fetch_all` uses less memory** (but not for so much).
>
> In my case (test1 and test2): 147008,262848 bytes (`fetch_all`) versus 147112,262888 bytes (`fetch_array` & `while`).
>
> **So, about the memory, in both cases are the same**.
>
> However, about the performance:
>
> My test takes **:350ms (worst case) using `fetch_all`**, while it takes **464ms (worst case) using `fetch_array`**, or about **35% worst using `fetch_array` and a `while` cycle**.
>
> So, **using `fetch_all`**, for a normal code that returns a moderate amount of information is:
>
> a. **cleaner** (a single line of code)
> b. **uses less memory** (about 0.01% less)
> c. **faster**.
>
> php 5.6 32bits, windows 8.1 64bits

Comment: I guess it depends on the definition of "normal code" and whether mysqli::use_result / mysqli::store_result / mysqli::reap_async_query has been taken into account.

Comment: This also only applies if you store all the data in memory at once. If you simply, e.g., `echo` a row in a loop and then discard it, `fetch_array` will probably use much less memory.