# What is best to use, fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) or fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)?

Tags: php, mysqli

They are two functions of mysqli_result.

- fetch_array(): Fetch a result row.

In this way, query for each row to the database?

- fetch_all(): Fetches all result rows.

And in this way, only query once to the database?

I do not know how to do it in the best way and the most efficient way.

Put examples:

1.-fetch_array():

```
$resultUsers = getAllUsers($db);
while($row = $resultUsers->fetch_array()){
     echo $row['name'];
}
```

2.- fetch_all():

```
$resultUsers = getAllUsers($db);
foreach ($resultUsers->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $value) {
    echo $value['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

2.A.-

```
foreach (getAllUser($db)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $value) {
    echo $value['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

If there is a better way to do it, I hope your help.

Comment: No, the query is run only once against the database in both cases; fetch works against the resultset from the query; and generally `fetch_all()` is very memory demanding for large result sets, so shouldn't realy be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case you need fetch_all() moved inside, as a function called getAllUsers() should get you all users, not mysqli result.

So it should be

```
$allUsers = getAllUsers($db);
```

and then $allUsers sent to a *template* for the output like

```
<?php foreach ($allUsers as $user) { ?>
    <?=$user['name']?>
>?} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big deal to consider. You can choose either of them based on your use case & usability.

[Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625944/mysqli-fetch-array-or-mysqli-fetch-all#answer-35626334)

But after all, Try to migrate to **PDO** *[PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)* ASAP. mysql*_functions are entirely removed in PHP 7.0 & most of them are considered deprecated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: `mysql` functions are deprecated/removed; but OP is using `mysqli` which is not deprecated or removed